# Move S3 objects to another folder in same bucket but with same permissions using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am able to move an object in an S3 bucket from one directory to another directory using C# but unable to copy all current permissions with that object.

For example, my current object has public access permissions but after moving it to another directory it lost the public read permissions.

Here is the code I'm using to move objects:

```
public void MoveFile(string sourceBucket, string destinationFolder, string file) {
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(ConfigurationHelper.AmazonS3AccessKey, ConfigurationHelper.AmazonS3SecretAccessKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        S3FileInfo currentObject = new S3FileInfo(s3Client, sourceBucket, file);
        currentObject.MoveTo(sourceBucket + "/" + destinationFolder, file);
    }
```

Here is the output after moving file to another directory:

[image]

It lost public "Read" permission.

Comment: Why have you tagged C# 3 and C# 4? Which version of the C# language have you instructed your compiler to use? Clearly it won't be both. Even C# 4 is almost 12 years old at this point.

Comment: @Llama I've tagged both because question may share with multiple users and I can get solution asap, do you have solution?

Comment: You're not supposed to add unrelated tags for the sake of additional exposure. That's how you earn downvotes. Suppose there was an answer to your question that perfectly solves the problem, but it's incompatible with C# 3 or perhaps C# 4 so the person who has that answer doesn't provide you with it. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: yeah I got it but I think you already removed additional tags ;)

Comment: The `MoveTo()` call actually performs a `CopyObject()` and then a `DeleteObject()`. Since it does not take any additional parameters, you cannot modify its behaviour. You will need to perform the Copy & Delete yourself, which will give the opportunity to specify appropriate permissions during the `CopyObject()` command.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you for your answer and it could be very helpful to me, I've posted answer to my own question so it could be helpful for someone. thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've figure out issue myself, by using CopyObject() and DeleteObject() instead of using moveTo inbuild method and that solves my issue,

here is the code which really helped me:

```
CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest
        {
            SourceBucket = sourceBucket,
            DestinationBucket = sourceBucket + "/" + destinationFolder,
            SourceKey = file,
            DestinationKey = file,
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
            StorageClass = S3StorageClass.StandardInfrequentAccess,
        };

        CopyObjectResponse response1 = s3Client.CopyObject(copyObjectRequest);

        var deleteObjectRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = sourceBucket,
            Key = file
        };

        s3Client.DeleteObject(deleteObjectRequest);
```

I'm posting answer so it can be helpful for someone!!!

Comment: Is there any another way by which we can move document from one folder to another within same S3 bucket rather than copying object and deleting it back. @dev2 itpathsolutions

Answer (score 0):

In my case it resolves by below code

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Moving file");
    var copyFileRequest = new CopyObjectRequest
    {
        SourceBucket = tempFile.Bucket.Name,
        SourceKey = tempFile.Object.Key,
        DestinationBucket = tempFile.Bucket.Name,
        DestinationKey = archiveFolder+"/"+tempFile.Object.Key,//Put archive folder path here
    };
    

    await s3Client.CopyObjectAsync(copyFileRequest);
    await s3Client.DeleteObjectAsync(tempFile.Bucket.Name, tempFile.Object.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("Moving done");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to move");
}
```